# How do I stop green flashes when playing video?

Tags: gnome, video, compiz, 15.10, vlc

I have Ubuntu 15.10, running Gnome Retro/Flashback/Fallback... whatever it's being called right now. I also have Compiz.

When I play videos in either VLC or Gnome Media player, the screen frequently flashes green. Put another way, every now and again, the whole screen turns completely green, but just for one frame or so. Sometimes this happens multiple times within one second, other times it just happens once. The frequency of when this occurs is random, but I'd say on average as often as once every minute or so.

This seems to have started roughly when I upgraded to 15.10, though I can't say with absolute certainty that the upgrade was the dividing factor. Before around that time, video playback worked perfectly.

This only affects local video files I play. YouTube and other online videos seem to work fine.

I found some suggestions on the web for how to fix this. One was to open Compizconfig and check the box for "Force full screen redraws (buffer swap) on repaint". The other solution I tried was specific to VLC, and in preferences I unchecked the "Accelerated video output (Overlay)" box. Unfortunately, neither suggestion worked.

How can I eradicate green flickering from my videos?

Comment: This is a Graphics driver problem, which graphics card you have, even internal.

Comment: @WeareBorg, I have an Nvida graphics card. I'm not sure which one.

Comment: Did you install graphics driver from softwares and updates?

Comment: @WeareBorg, I believe I have the latest Nvidia drivers installed.

Comment: Did you checked it in Sofwares and updates and the restricted drivers section, post a screenshot please.

Comment: @Questioner, Does it happen with all types of videos FLV, WEBM, MP4, OGG? Could you try setting "Hardware-accelerated decoding" in "Input/Codecs" tab to " Video Acceleration (VA) API" & "Disable".

Answer (score 1):

From settings video output to OpenGL or something other than you are currently using.

Answer (score 0):

Hi it sounds like you are experiencing some codec issues I resolved the same problem by installing the restricted pack from ubuntu you can install it buy typing the following in the terminal

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Take note that it might be illegal in some country's

Comment: Thanks for responding. When I type that command, I get `ubuntu-restricted-extras is already the newest version`.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I needed to lower my post-processing setting in VLC.
Disable it to see if you no longer get any green screen issues and then increase it incrementally to find the sweet spot.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the **Tools** menu and select **Preferences**.
2. Click on the **Video** tab and change the setting  in **Video - Deinterlacing** to **Off**.

Answer (score 0):

it certainly had to do with the deinterlacing, but I couldn't fix it turning it off or playing around with the modes.
MPV Media Player did the trick for me. it played the Videos without a problem I hope that can help.

Answer (score -1):

1)  The "green flashing screens" is a very old "de-interlacing" bug
    which has persisted in VLC player for years.

2)  It is common to all hardware, drivers and operating systems,
    including windows.

3)  Depending on whether the player starts by rendering odd or even frames,
    the flashing may (or may not) occur every time you play, start, rewind
    or fast forward a film.

4)  The flashing is therefore intermittent, neither consistent nor repeatable.

5)  It occurs in different movie segments at different times in the same file.

6)  It happens only in certain movie files, most often in ripped DVD's,
    which contain multiple 1 GB files inside a VIDEO_TS folder.

7)  It could also (therefore) be the result of incorrect HDCP decoding during
    the unauthorized DVD rips, using tools like "SlyFox anyDVD", such that the
    resulting (malformed) files confuse the de-interlacing algorithms in VLC player.

8)  In all cases I have experienced, disabling video de-interlacing in VLC player
    seems to fix the problem, at the cost of jittery, poor video playback, with a
    low line count.

9)  The problem does not seem to effect HD movies in single "Matroska" vid containers.

===
BTW:
I wish people in forums stopped trying to sound smart,
by flooding the forums with dumb "Generic" answers like:
"Do you have the latest driver update?" ... or

## "Is your mouse plugged in?" ... LOL.

Then 100,000 other web sites scrape and reprint these IDIOTIC
statements and reprint them as their own, flooding the Internet

## with worthless spam.

Empty cans need to stop making so much noise!

===

Comment: Hmm, this one you mean? https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/issues/20343